# How to get response text asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I am trying to get the response text from an URL using ajax. The code below works fine if I set the `async` flag to `false` but I get a warning from jQuery saying

> jquery.min.js:4 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

Here is the code:

```
function verifyUser()
{
    var response = $.ajax({type: "GET", url: "/verify/4512h58", async: false}).responseText;
    console.log(response);
}
```

and if I set the `async` flag to `true` like so

```
var response = $.ajax({type: "GET", url: "/verify/112358", async: true}).responseText;
```

I get `undefined` as output. How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses something called promises so it needs to look something like this...

```
var response = $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/verify/4512h58"
}).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

[See for more info](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the callback

```
var response = "";
$.ajax({type: "GET", url: "/verify/112358", async: true})
     .then(function(x){
        response = x.responseText
     });
```

See also [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323)

Comment: With 20k rep you should know to flag this over asked question as a duplicate rather than answering it again

Comment: @andrew - I did, see the comment below the question.

Comment: So... you just wanted to make it more difficult to delete?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - questions are not deleted frequently and especially not if its a true duplicate. Instead it will get marked as such but hang around in the system.

Comment: I thought they got picked up by the Roomba, but apparently that doesn't include duplicates. My apologies.